# Can PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE be set using config files in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to set the PDO / Doctrine config in Symfony2 to use `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true` without using PDO directly?

My use case is loading a csv file into MySQL on Amazon RDS. Symfony version is 2.4

I get the error:

```
PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden in /.../vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php on line 165
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can set it in your `config.yml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        options:
            "PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE": 1
```

The key must be quoted, because of the colons it contains.

Comment: This didn't work for me, wouldn't it pass the option as the literal string instead of the constant value?

It looks like loading constants in the YAML is a new feature: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-php-constants-in-yaml-files

Answer (score 0):

Using Symfony >=3.2, the syntax is:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    options:
      !php/const:PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE: 1
```

If you have multiple connections, use:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    connections:
      my_connection:
        options:
          !php/const:PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE: 1
```